# Prove that a graph with $n$ vertices, where each vertex has at least $\frac{n}{2}$ degrees, is connected.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple undirected graph with $n \geq 2$ vertices. Prove that if each vertex has at least $\frac{n}{2}$ degrees, then $G$ is connected.

I'm lost on how to approach this problem and what proof technique to use. From testing examples I know that it is true but not sure how to start. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: HINT: If $G$ is not connected, it is the disjoint union of subgraphs $G_1$ and $G_2$. What’s the maximum degree of a vertex in the smaller of these subgraphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $G$ is not connected, it has more than one connected component. The smallest component has at most $n/2$ vertices. What does that say about the degrees of vertices in that small component?

Comment: I understand what to do now and I've arrived at a contradiction. Thank you very much. I have a follow-up question: how exactly we do we know that the smallest component has at most $\frac{n}{2}$ vertices?

Comment: @curlypie99 If the smallest component has $>n/2$ vertices, then all components have $>n/2$ vertices, so the total number of vertices is $>n$.

Answer (score 1):

If works already with $\frac{n-1}2$ in place of $\frac n2$.

Let $a,b$  be two distinct vertices. If there is no direct edge $ab$ and they have no common neighbour, then their neighbours make up at least $\frac{n-1}2+\frac{n-1}2$ other vertices, but there are only $n-2$ - contradiction. (So in particular, we even see that $G$ has diameter $\le 2$)